# Wordpress - post visible only to a specific user

Tags: wordpress

Is there any plugin that allow me to set up the website in this way?
User A of a Wordpress-based website can view only the post #1.
User B can view only posts #2 and #3.
User C can view only posts #1 and #3.
User D can view all posts.

Every user is registered manually by the admin, who will provide the username and password to the client and will select manually the post every user can view.

Thank you.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: the question have been edited by another user, i modified it again with the explicit question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure something like [This](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-specific-content/) will do what you need.

> ### User Specific Content
>
> By Bainternet
>
> This Plugin allows you to select specific users by user name, or by role name who can view a specific post content or page content.
>
> Basically it adds a meta box to the post or page edit screen and lets the user select specific users by name or roles and then when you call that page content using “the_content();” function it check using “the_content” filter if the current user is one of the users you have selected or if his role match’s the roles you have selected and shows the content, otherwise it displays a message

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin named "**WP Private Content Plus**" by Rakhitha Nimesh

This plugin gives you the option to hide the content of the post for selected users. Also you can show the post content to a specific user as well.